# Mail and dhcp server in a closed network

Tags: networking, server, email, dhcp, postfix

Here is my needs;

I need a mailserver (with one account) that can receive mails from several other systems on a closed network (no internet access after installation) and two network interfaces. There are several users that should be able to connect to read the mails from a pop/imap client. 
Its for detecting errors on other systems in my network. How can i set this up as easy as possible?

I am going to set up my own dhcp server to, so if there is anything i need to do with this to?

I have Ubuntu 15.10 server installed with only CLI..

Any tutorials or anything to guide me would be appreciated as i can not find any that i am sure will work in my network like this.